# WPF - Observable Sorted Dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, dictionary, observablecollection, sorteddictionary

I have a requirement to push high volumes of data into a DataGrid (I would prefer a DataGrid as it is fit for purpose for the requirement I have).  To make the UI more responsive while the data is being loaded and as the data is coming in after the initial load is complete, something fairly high performance is required.  On top of that the data needs to be sorted (descending order based on date).  As it is only updated from one thread being concurrent (and/or immutable) is not really required (from what I understand being concurrent and/or immutable may slow down the load in any case).  So for this reason I would like to implement an Observable performant collection such as a SortedDictionary

From what I have seen the above isn't readily available - the options I have seen are http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208361/Concurrent-Observable-Collection-Dictionary-and-So but this isn't bindable to a DataGrid (more toward a ListView).  The other is http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/ which is based on a Dictionary and hand sorts (which seems counter-intuitive since there is already a SortedDictionary - and again doesn't seem to bind to a DataGrid easily).

The below is what I have

```
public class ObservableSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IObservableSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private const string CountString = "Count";
    private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";
    private const string KeysName = "Keys";
    private const string ValuesName = "Values";

    private int _capacity = 0;

    private SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;
    protected SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary
    {
        get { return _dictionary; }
        private set { _dictionary = value; }
    }

    #region Fields
    private readonly SimpleMonitor _monitor;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ObservableSortedDictionary(IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        this._monitor = new SimpleMonitor();
        CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ObservableSortedDictionary_CollectionChanged);
        _dictionary = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer);
    }
    public ObservableSortedDictionary(int capacity, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        this._monitor = new SimpleMonitor();
        _capacity = capacity;
        CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ObservableSortedDictionary_CollectionChanged);
        _dictionary = (new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer));         }
    public ObservableSortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        }
        CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ObservableSortedDictionary_CollectionChanged);
        this._monitor = new SimpleMonitor();
        _dictionary = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, comparer);
    }
    public ObservableSortedDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IComparer<TKey> comparer, int capacity)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        }
        CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ObservableSortedDictionary_CollectionChanged); 
        this._monitor = new SimpleMonitor();
        _capacity = capacity;
        try
        {
            _dictionary = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, comparer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Insert(key, value, true);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return Dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return Dictionary.Keys; }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        CheckReentrancy(); 
        TValue value;
        Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        var removed = Dictionary.Remove(key);
        if (removed)
            OnCollectionChanged();

        return removed;
    }


    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }


    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { return Dictionary.Values; }
    }


    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return Dictionary[key];
        }
        set
        {
            Insert(key, value, false);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members
    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        Insert(item.Key, item.Value, true);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        if (Dictionary.Count > 0)
        {
            CheckReentrancy(); 
            Dictionary.Clear();
            OnCollectionChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return Dictionary.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Dictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return Dictionary.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)Dictionary).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return Remove(item.Key);
    }
    #endregion


    #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged Members
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    #endregion


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    public void AddRange(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> items)
    {
        if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            if (items.Keys.Any((k) => Dictionary.ContainsKey(k)))
                throw new ArgumentException("An item with the same key has already been added.");
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(item.Key, item.Value));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        CheckReentrancy(); 
        TValue item;
        if (Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out item))
        {
            if (add) throw new ArgumentException("An item with the same key has already been added.");
            if (Equals(item, value)) return;
            Dictionary[key] = value;

            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value), new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, item));
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary[key] = value;
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
            if (_capacity > 0 && Dictionary.Count > _capacity)
            {
                Dictionary.Remove(Dictionary.Keys.Last());
                OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
            }
        }
    }

    #region SimpleMonitor
    protected IDisposable BlockReentrancy()
    {
        this._monitor.Enter();
        return this._monitor;
    }

    protected void CheckReentrancy()
    {
        if ((this._monitor.Busy && (CollectionChanged != null)) && (CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList().Length > 1))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Collection Reentrancy Not Allowed");
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class SimpleMonitor : IDisposable
    {
        private int _busyCount;

        public bool Busy
        {
            get { return this._busyCount > 0; }
        }

        public void Enter()
        {
            this._busyCount++;
        }

        #region Implementation of IDisposable

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this._busyCount--;
        }

        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

    private void OnPropertyChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
        OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
        OnPropertyChanged(KeysName);
        OnPropertyChanged(ValuesName);
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (CollectionChanged != null) using (BlockReentrancy()) { CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));}
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> changedItem)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (CollectionChanged != null) using (BlockReentrancy()) { CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, changedItem));}
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> newItem, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> oldItem)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (CollectionChanged != null) using (BlockReentrancy()) {CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem));}
    }


    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, IList newItems)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (CollectionChanged != null) using (BlockReentrancy()) {CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItems));}
    }

    void ObservableSortedDictionary_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                ((KeyValuePair<TickerKey, TickerViewModel>)(item)).Value.PropertyChanged += ObservableSortedDictionary_PropertyChanged;                 }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems)
            {
                ((KeyValuePair<TickerKey, TickerViewModel>)(item)).Value.PropertyChanged -= ObservableSortedDictionary_PropertyChanged;                 }
        }
    }

    void ObservableSortedDictionary_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (e.PropertyName == "Dictionary")
            OnPropertyChanged("Dictionary");
    }
}

public interface IObservableSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
}
```

The ViewModel

```
    //...
    private ObservableSortedDictionary<TickerKey, TickerViewModel> _tickersData;
    public ObservableSortedDictionary<TickerKey, TickerViewModel> TickersData
    {
        get
        {
            return _tickersData;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _tickersData)
            {
                _tickersData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TickersData");
            }
        }
    }
    //...
    if (TickersData == null)
    {
        TickerComparer comparer = new TickerComparer();
        TickersData = new ObservableSortedDictionary<TickerKey, TickerViewModel>(_tickersInsert, comparer, 50);
    }
    else
    {
        TickersData.AddRange(_tickersInsert);
        foreach (var item in _tickersInsert) TickersData.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
    //...
```

The View (XAML)

```
//...
<DataGrid FontSize="9" x:Name="Ticker1Tickers" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TickersData.Values}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TickerPrice}" Header="Price" Width="50"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TickerVolume}" Header="Volume" Width="50" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TickerTimeMilliSecondsSinceMidnight, Converter={StaticResource mmSsFormatConverter}, StringFormat=\{0:hh:mm:ss tt\}}" Header="Time" Width="70" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
//...
```

A few things of note

- The above loads the DataGrid initially with rows from the database but as new data comes in, this is not reflected within the DataGrid (even though the new data is added to the ObservableSortedDictionary.
- The binding of the ObservableSortedDictionary to the XAML is via the Values part of the dictionary (i.e. TickersData.Values rather than simply TickersData)
- the weakness seems to be within the CollectionChanged/PropertyChanged notification.  Specifically between sending the event from a change to the dictionary Values collection down to the DataGrid

Has anyone attempted anything like the above and/or can see where the notification issue may be ?

**UPDATE**
After Pieter's suggestion I have changed the XAML DataGrid definition to

```
<DataGrid FontSize="9" x:Name="Ticker1Tickers" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TickersData}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.TickerPrice}" Header="Price" Width="50"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.TickerVolume}" Header="Volume" Width="50" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.TickerTimeMilliSecondsSinceMidnight, Converter={StaticResource mmSsFormatConverter}, StringFormat=\{0:hh:mm:ss tt\}}" Header="Time" Width="70" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why not just use an ObservableCollection and then insert at the appropriate position to maintain a sort?  And if you need performance then why DataGrid?

Comment: You're binding to `TickersData.Values` - the `Values` property of your sorted dictionary, not the sorted dictionary itself. Try binding to `TickersData` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Frisbee - I understand what you're saying around ObservableCollection, but I don't want to engineer my own sort algo (which will not be as performant as say an out of the box sorted collection).  And the reason for the DataGrid (rather than say ListView) is because out of the box it has the required functionality (column sorting, etc)

Comment: Thanks Pieter - Binding to the ObservableSortedDictionary (TickersData) directly isn't able to distinguish column fields to bind to (i.e. the fields occur within the Keys or Values collection).  When bound to TickersData (as opposed to TickersData.Values) the DataGrid simply displays blank rows

Comment: Your data-grid won't react to collection-changed events if it's not directly bound to your collection itself. So either bind directly to `TickersData` or make its `Values` property something that implements `IObservableCollection`. Is there a specific reason for exposing these items in the form of a dictionary? UI controls will see that as a collection of key-value pairs. Things become much easier if you provide your UI with a collection of values instead.

Comment: Many thanks Pieter - I've modified the XAML to point directly at the ObservableSortedDictionary (rather than the Values property), and modified the column Bindings - I've posted an update within the original post.  
So it (the DataGrid) is now updating as new data comes in.  However, although the data is being added (and persisted) into the SortedDictionary in the desired order, the new data is simply being added to the end of the DataGrid - is there a means to reflect the actual order of the SortedDictionary into the DataGrid (refresh, etc) ?

Comment: @TerrorBight: You may want to read up on [collection views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx). It may well be that using an `ObservableCollection<T>` in combination with either a [custom collection view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or a default one that you control will be sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your assistance along the way on this Pieter.  To refresh/sort the DataGrid from the ObservableSortedDictionary I found The solution (after reading one of the comments in http://programmer.wrighton.org/2009/01/wpf-datagrid-items-refresh.html) was

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TickersData).Refresh();
```

Hopefully the above statement isn't too much of a resource overhead

I had one further issue that related to the OnCollectionChanged - the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs required an index (as opposed to the item) of the SortedDictionary which is doesn't come out of the box (it's easier with a SortedList, but anyhow).

But all OK now - working well